# Google App Engine - Eclipse Authentication

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I have the Eclipse GAE Plugin keeping memory of a previous Google Authentication and thus not allowing me to upload a GAE app associated to a different account. The strange thing is that I can't find any GAE button at the bottom of My Eclipse Installation (as mentioned in some docs on the Internet). The only thing I have managed to do is to add the --no_cookies option in the upload command which opens a new tab in chrome allowing me to provide the right auth.

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to update the Eclipse configuration so I have to do it at any upload.

How should I fix that?

Comment: There are more that one Eclipse plugins out there. Can you clarify which one you are using? The one from developers.google.com/eclipse?